# Minecraft scheduleSyncRepeatingTask Bukkit to another class

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a Bukkit plugin where I need to update in a loop.

I'm using:

```
Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this,
        new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       // CODE
    }
}, 60, 100);
```

within my `onEnable` method, but I can't start or stop the method or even getting it.

I want to give a player an `Item` each second to amount of the item he needs is in the method in another class in an `EventHandler`.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here are expected to __target specific programming problems__ - What's the _expected behaviour_, _specific error or unexpected behaviour you're getting_ (A clear problem statement), and a ___reproducible example___? Please take a __[tour]__. Also see a [__Minimal__, __Complete__, and __Verifiable__ example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [__Short__, __Self Contained__, Correct (__Compilable__) example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: See [BukkitScheduler](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming#BukkitScheduler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using BukkitRunnable, especially since [your way of scheduling tasks is deprecated in recent bukkits](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/commit/8d5b4c1e9acc499377da0d807e7ca2245d5c3bdf).

What you should be doing is making a new class that extends BukkitRunnable, then make an instance of it and run

`runTaskTimer(<plugininstance>, 60, 100);`

on it, and you can later run

`cancel();`

on the same instance of the BukkitRunnable to stop it.

http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming

Comment: Are you sure we can use `this.cancel()` on the class?

Comment: [yes](http://jd.bukkit.org/dev/apidocs/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html#cancel())

Comment: Can you give me please an example?

Comment: I don't get it can you please give some information of it? @hintss

Comment: what info do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class implementing Runnable.

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
    //do something
    }
}
```

Then you can schedule it using

```
Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new MyTask(), 60, 100);
```

if you want to schedule the task from other class like EventHandler you may write a grtInstance() method in your main class or you can use `Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("yourplugin")` to retrieve your plugin main class instance.

Comment: I cant' use an eventhandler in the run method , but I want a class with the refresher that you can call from another class. I want that a method keeps running overagain

Comment: So you want to call the run() method from eventhandler?

Comment: in eventhandler is an if statement that hav to run evry 1 second

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Can you put it like 'start it' , 'stop it' , 'Your scheduler code' , 'Normal code' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an id to the scheduler, with the right parameters you can then access it from other classes.
Also, use BukkitRunnables
You are able to cancel it via this.cancel in the scheduler itself then.